# django-haystack - auto-complete with tokens

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack to create some search functionality. I want to auto-complete on the search input with common tokens. How can I do that?

Example:

If I have in the index 3 documents with:

```
   only one 
   only me 
   only you
```

And I want to set autocomplete "on", I want to show "only" and "one", preferably in this order.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you had a gander at this page, https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html#step-2-performing-the-query which notes some of the options regarding autocomplete tokens, ngram, etc.?

Comment: Autocomplete gives me search results, I need common tokens in the index